# What do I need to do to get MVC to work on IIS7? Does not show page, just shows directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I've just file system deployed an intranet site to one of our internal servers. The site is configured with it's own application pool w/.net 4. The site is configured to allow anonymous access. The NetworkServices account has read access to the directory/s. For trouble shooting purposes I have directory listing enabled.

When I hit the site I get the directory listing, why does the home/index page not come up as expected? Other servers that I have deployed to have just worked. I can not seem to find a difference here.

Also I have the site configured to come up as http: //myip:8081/

I've already run aspnet_regiis -I and checked to make sure the pool was the correct version.

I rolled back my .Net version from 4.5.1 to 4 and reinstalled all the nugget packages.
I have copied local all the DLLs just to be sure.

Comment: Please make sure your routes are mapped correctly. You will need a default route to the Home/Index path. Routes are defined in  App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

Comment: The apps are mapped correctly. The site runs great on my local iis and on another test server that I am using.

Comment: It's unfortunately hard to say without being able to actually dig into your server setup. There's nothing special about deploying an MVC site to IIS7, especially versus a different version of IIS. In general, make sure that .NET Framework is installed at the right version (it's common to get bit by something silly like a site compiled for 4.5.1, but deployed to a server with only 4.5 installed, for example). However, I'd expect you to get an error then, rather than directory listing. Make sure your site is setup correctly in IIS. Try republishing. It may just take some trial and error.

Comment: I originally had it as a 4.5.1 package and realized the mistake and rolled everything including the nugget packages back to 4 but still no luck.

Comment: Might recommend installing Elmah or using some kind of logging tool to get more insight.

Comment: Good suggestion. Elmah is part of my startup template for all my projects. In this case it was not showing anything. What I ended up doing is creating a new project and copying all my code files into the new project. Built and deployed and it all works great now. Go figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original project was targeted to .Net 4.5 and I had down-converted to 4.  I thought I had changed all references and configuration items but I must have missed something.

I created a new project targeting .Net 4 and copied my code files into the new project.

Compiled and deployed and all worked correctly.

Not sure what item in the web.config wasn't changed (or maybe something else in the project) but this worked and was fairly quick.